# C# webbrowser string

Tags: c#, string, browser

I have that code

```
 HtmlElementCollection classButton = form1.webBrowser1.Document.All;
 foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
 {
     if (element.GetAttribute("tip") == "<b>mob1</b><i>hero</i><span>25 lvl</span>")
     {
          string idmoba = element.Id;
          form1.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(idmoba).InvokeMember("click");
```

Is possible to detect element.Id by several characters? For example
`if (element.GetAttribute("tip") == "<b>mob1</b>"` + function that capture other words

Comment: You can do it with XML Linq.

Comment: `if (element.GetAttribute("tip").StartsWith("<b>mob1</b>")) ...` ?  Also you can call `InvokeMember` on the `element` variable.